# Ошибка Xcode при запуске на симуляторе или девайсе

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

При запуске отображается пустой белый экран и в дебагере пишет "MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform". Обновил xcode до 10 версии, нашел одно обсуждение, говорят что из-за этого. Но сколько можно ждать исправления, может кто-то уже решил эту проблему?

Comment: Так а что изменилось, почему стала появляться ошибка?

Comment: Просто обновил Xcode, до этого все работало корректно. Теперь при запуске симулятора приложение не падает, но на экране симулятора пусто...

Comment: Попробуйте скачать xcode с сайта apple и установить?